# How to lock a SQL record with LinqToSql?

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, locking, datacontext, linqdatasource

I'm using a LinqToSql DataContext and I want to lock a record for being opened in write mode.  Meaning while one user in Hong Kong has a record open in write mode, another user in France can't open that record in write mode.  How?

Comment: Is this a connected or disconnected app (winform? webapp?)

Comment: are you asking of SQL table lock or a mechanism for preventing more then one user to work on specific entity from higher level in the application

Comment: Not a table lock.  A record lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LinqToSql supports optimistic concurrency, not pessimistic concurrency.